# Lightning: can't train on GPU after loading submodule from disk

Tags: pytorch, pyro, lightning

I have a LightningModule that looks something like this:

```py
class MyModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        self.module1 = Module1()
        self.module2 = Module2()

    def save(path):
        torch.save((self.module1, self.module2), path)

    def load(path):
        obj = torch.load(path)
        self.module1 = obj[0]
        self.module2 = obj[1]
```

Now I want to train it on GPU using

```py
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu")
trainer.fit(model=mymodule)
```

This works in a notebook with a newly started kernel. After training, I save the module to disk. I can restart the kernel, create a new MyModule, load the state from disk and continue training. What doesn't work is reloading from disk without restarting the kernel. So basically

```py
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu")
trainer.fit(model=mymodule)
mymodule.save("test.pt")
mymodule.load("test.pt")
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu")
trainer.fit(model=mymodule)
```

results in

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument tensors in method wrapper_CUDA_cat)
```

where the exact place where the exception is thrown varies. Puzzlingly, if I enter the post-mortem debugger with `%debug` and go up the stack to the training_step of MyModule, `self.device` is `cpu` and not `cuda`.

I've tried running garbage collection followed by `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. I've also tried

```py
def load(path):
    del self.module1
    del self.module2
    obj = torch.load(path)
    self.module1 = obj[0]
    self.module2 = obj[1]
```

without any effect.

It might be worth mentioning that module1 is a Pyro model and module2 is a Pyro guide (this is also why I can't just save the state_dict, as the guide creates the trainable parameters only when it sees the first minibatch). Both are subclasses of `pyro.nn.PyroModule`, which itself subclasses `torch.nn.Module`.

Comment: I suggest to move both modules to `cpu` before saving, and to move them to `self.device` when loading. If you provide an MRE it could be useful to further debug you issue.